# Google API Combo Chart Font Issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, google-api

I am having an issue with Google API's Combo Chart control in IE8. I can't seem to get the fonts correct for the chart.

This is my function that draws the chart: (all fonts explicitly called out here, I've also attempted to only set it on the iframe property (that is only used in IE8))

```
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            fontName: 'Arial',
            slantedText: false,
            titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'Arial', slantedText: false },
            title: 'PLMs for Period',
            tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: 'Arial', italic: false, fontSize: 24} },
            vAxis: { title: '# of PLM\'s', titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'Arial', slantedText: false, fontSize: '24', bold: true} },
            hAxis: { title: 'Plant Location', titleTextStyle: { fontName: 'Arial', slantedText: false, fontSize: '24', bold: true} },
            seriesType: "bars",
            series: { 5: { type: "line"} },
            backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
            titleTextStyle: { fontSize: '28' }
        };
        var arrayTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
        chart.draw(arrayTable, options);
    }
```

Here is the relevant HTML Code:

```
    <div id="report-container">
        <h3 id="period-information"></h3>
        <div id="report-content">
            <h3 id="InProgressStart-header"></h3>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="InProgressStart-content">
            </div>
            <h3 id="Launched-header"></h3>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="Launched-content">
            </div>
            <h3 id="Completed-header"></h3>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="Completed-content">
            </div>
            <h3 id="InProgressEnd-header"></h3>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="InProgressEnd-content">
            </div>
            <h3 id="Rejected-header"></h3>
            <div class="accordion-content" id="Rejected-content">
            </div>
        </div>
        <center><div id="chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div></center>
    </div>
```

Here is an example of the data being passed in:

```
    [
        ["Plant Location", "In Progress at Start", "Launched", "Completed", "In Progress at End", "Fully Rejected"],
        ["Example 1", 17, 6, 8, 15, 1],
        ["Example 2", 19, 5, 8, 14, 2],
        ["Example 3", 12, 6, 3, 14, 1]
    ]
```

Here are the styles that involve fonts:

```
    iframe
    {
        font-family: "Arial, sans-serif";   
    }
    body {
        color: #333;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0  auto;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 1200px;
        min-width: 500px;
        background: #F2F2F2;
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more information. I've done a bit of research on my own and seen that IE is dependent on the OS's fonts, but it should still render 'Arial' correctly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You explain quite well what you've done, but what is your question? You say you can't get the correct fonts, but what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Cthulhu, thanks for the welcome! The issue isn't an error, the fonts aren't rendering correctly. I wish I could upload an image, but I don't have enough rep yet. Here is a link to one though: http://imgur.com/otqlI2m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround on Google Groups. When entering fontName's into Google API Visualization controls, enter the value wrapped in double quotes, and then single quotes. Like this: '"fontName"', this makes it render correctly in IE8. (Fix found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/ESS5mDoqrc0)

Google does know about this issue, but doesn't plan on fixing it. This is the response from Google: "We're sorry about it, but don't know what can be done. IE <= 8 doesn't support SVG, so VML is used. More over, VML support in IE is deteriorating, and fonts handling is particularly problematic. IE9 finally supports SVG and I think this works fine there, but we were unable to fix the issues for IE <= 8." (from: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=427)